# Javascript não exibe valor na tela

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia, boa tarde e boa noite!

Eu estou desenvolvendo um jogo estilo cli de pergunta e resposta em HTML e Javascript. Porém a minha função do javascript não exibe a resposta na tela.
 Segue o código:

```js
funcaoJogo = function(){
 document.getElementById('tela').innerText = document.getElementById('inputValor').value;
 alert("Bem vindo a Cidade das Batalhas");
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: gray;
 color: white;
}

div#tela {
 margin: auto;
 padding: auto;
 background-color: black;
 width: 640px;
 height: 480px;
 overflow: auto;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

div#resposta {
 margin: auto;
 padding: auto;
 background-color: #B22222;
 width: 640px;
 height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title>IA GAME</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2/newCss.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript2/newJavascript.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="tela">
</div>

<div id="resposta">
<center>
  Jogador Nº1:
  <input id="inputValor" type="text" name="">
  <button id="enviar" onclick="funcaoJogo">Desafiar</button>
</center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço! Valeu, falou!

Answer (score 2):

Faltou os parênteses no `onclick`, precisa deles para chamar a função

```js
funcaoJogo = function() {
  document.getElementById('tela').innerText = document.getElementById('inputValor').value;
  alert("Bem vindo a Cidade das Batalhas");
}
```

```html
<div id="tela"></div>

<div id="resposta">
  <center>
    Jogador Nº1:
    <input id="inputValor" type="text" name="">
    <button id="enviar" onclick="funcaoJogo()">Desafiar</button>
  </center>
</div>
```